SyntaxError: The requested module '@aws-amplify/platform-core' does not provide an export named 'CallerDirectoryExtractor'
I created a lambda function using gen2 as follow:
amplify/functions/send-link-file/resource.ts file:
import { defineFunction } from '@aws-amplify/backend';
export const sendReportEmail = defineFunction({
  name: 'send-report-email',
  entry: './handler.ts',
  timeoutSeconds: 180
});

hander.ts file:
import {SendRawEmailCommand, SESClient, } from '@aws-sdk/client-ses';
import { CreateForm1 } from './pdf';
const sesClient = new SESClient({region: 'ap-south-1'});
export const handler = async (event: any, context: any) =\> {
\------ rest of the logic...
return 'success';
}

backend.ts file:
import { defineBackend } from '@aws-amplify/backend';
import {Effect, PolicyStatement} from "aws-cdk-lib/aws-iam"
import { auth } from './auth/resource.js';
import { data } from './data/resource.js';
import { sendLinkEmail } from './functions/send-link-email/resource';
import { sendReportEmail } from './functions/send-report-email/resource';
const backend = defineBackend({
auth,
data,
sendLinkEmail,
sendReportEmail
});

Everything works well in sandbox. But while deployment, I am getting following error:

2024-09-22T19:41:30.538Z \[INFO\]: # Executing command: npx ampx pipeline-deploy --branch $AWS_BRANCH --app-id $AWS_APP_ID --debug

54 2024-09-22T19:41:55.774Z \[INFO\]: \[DEBUG\] 2024-09-22T19:41:55.773Z: npm

55 2024-09-22T19:41:55.780Z \[INFO\]: \[DEBUG\] 2024-09-22T19:41:55.774Z: WARN exec The following package was not found and will be installed: cdk@2.159.1

56 2024-09-22T19:42:00.121Z \[INFO\]: \[DEBUG\] 2024-09-22T19:42:00.120Z: /codebuild/output/src4216656133/src/medical-amplify/node_modules/@aws-amplify/backend-function/src/factory.ts:35

57 CallerDirectoryExtractor,
^

59 SyntaxError: The requested module '@aws-amplify/platform-core' does not provide an export named 'CallerDirectoryExtractor'

60 at ModuleJob.\_instantiate (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:124:21)

61 at async ModuleJob.run (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:190:5)

How can I solve this issue?


I am trying to use aws amplify gen2 functions. `


It's a dependency mismatch. That class was added very recently, and I'm guessing you have a version mismatch between some of the amplify modules. What does your package.json look like?
